# Helm template condition check for string does not work as expected

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates, sprig-template-functions

```
  WARNING: jp-osa do not have regional COS endpoint support, it is recommended to use Cross-Regional Storageclass.
```

And the code snippet I have in NOTES.txt for this helm chart is:

```
 {{- if not (contains  $.Values.region "storage-plugin.regionEP") }}
  WARNING: {{ $.Values.region }} do not have regional COS endpoint support, it is recommended to use Cross-Regional Storageclass.

  {{- end }
```

When I print `storage-plugin.regionEP` I see  `.au-syd.br-sao.ca-tor.eu-de.eu-fr2.eu-gb.jp-osa.jp-tok.us-east.us-south`

and the `region` values is `jp-osa`.

If condition should ideally not get executed. Any idea why this is not working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it set up, it is looking for the string "jp-osa" inside the literal string "storage-plugin.regionEP", not a variable or template.  Since it does not match, the `if` statement is always true.

I'm guessing you have a template in `_helpers.tpl` called `storage-plugin.regionEP`, which you are trying to call. In this case, you need to use the following:

```
 {{- if not (contains  $.Values.region (include "storage-plugin.regionEP" $)) }}
  WARNING: {{ $.Values.region }} do not have regional COS endpoint support, it is recommended to use Cross-Regional Storageclass.

  {{- end }
```

The `(include "storage-plugin.regionEP" $)` should return the string `.au-syd.br-sao.ca-tor.eu-de.eu-fr2.eu-gb.jp-osa.jp-tok.us-east.us-south`. The `contains` will then return `true` and the `if` statement will be rendered `false`.